# Remove backslash from url string with alamofire in swift3

Tags: swift3, escaping, alamofire

I'm trying to call a web API.

The parameter needs to include double-quoted string but not allowed to have backslash.
So far, I tried and have the following code.

```
let method = "helloWorld"
let parameters = "param1=test&param2={keywords:[" + "\"Hello\"" + "],type:" +  "\"General\"" + "}"
let convertedParameters = parameters.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\", with: "")
let path = baseURL + method + "?" + convertedParameters
let response = Alamofire.request(path, method: .get)
        .responseJSON()
```

This gives an error at backslash(escape string).
Finally, the link looks like the following.

https://example.com/api/hellowWorld?param1=test&param2={keywords:[\"Hello\"],type:\"General\"}

Then, I remove the backslashes manually, paste it in web browser and it works properly.

https://example.com/api/hellowWorld?param1=test&param2={keywords:["Hello"],type:"General"}

It is pretty hard to request the change of web API and I want to treat this tiny problem on my side.
Is it technically possible?

I appreciate if someone helps me.

Comment: Your `parameters` string does not contain backslashes. The backslashes in your Swift code are not actual backslashes. Try `print(parameters)`.

Comment: Yes, actually it was not web API problem. The problem was how to set parameters in alamofire.

Comment: So how does your current code not work?